# Modelsim ( Questasim 10.1) save results from a certain time and see schematic data

Tags: simulation, modelsim, questasim

I ve launched a simulation for reproducing a bug. The bug happens after 1s of simulation time and so the simulation last too much.
Is there a way to save only the waveform and the other infos from a certain point of the simulation (i.e. after 1s)? Can this speed up the simulation?

I ve also another question. In this simulation i did not save the .dbg. i tried to open the schematic for debugging but it did not appear ( it says that debug data does not match loaded design). is there a way to open the schemayic in this case?
I m using Questasim 10.1.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: The command `run 1 sec` runs the simulation for 1 second. If you want to view the waveform use `add wave` command as described in: https://www.microsemi.com/document-portal/doc_view/136364-modelsim-me-10-4c-command-reference-manual-for-libero-soc-v11-7

If you want to save the signals to a VCD file to plot them later, see `vcd add` command